# Printing raw code on page

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to print raw html with PHP like this:

```
<?php
$head = htmlspecialchars('<head></head>',ENT_QUOTES);
echo $head; 
?>
```

This works nothing wrong with it if you are willing to print this ammount of html.

The problem is what if i want to print alot of html. Look at the picture below:

[image]

It comes out really messy. I want to add some line breaks in between, but if i do this it will just print `<br/>` right?

Comment: Just a note: use `<pre>` HTML tag to display the generated code. It will be nicer :)

Comment: thanks @iSS helped me

Comment: @mirokai: y u deleted your answer?

Comment: someone downvoted, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your html output in `<pre>` tags to keep the intial formatting.

So your code would change to :

```
<?php
$head = htmlspecialchars('<head></head>',ENT_QUOTES);
echo "<pre>".$head."</pre>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Man, I totally forgot about <pre>.. Thanks a lot, accepting in a bit!

Comment: <pre> is the better solution